# MacPorts linker (ld) not found

Tags: linker, macports

I'm trying to compile cgminer on Mac, and the compilation cannot complete, citing "ld: library not found for -lrt"

Exact terminal output:

```
  CCLD     cgminer
ld: library not found for -lrt
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [cgminer] Error 1
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
```

Any solution for how to install the linker library via command line?

Comment: librt is (as far as I know) not available for Mac OS X. Could you try plain removing it from the makefile?

Comment: You'll have to walk me through that...My knowledge of Unix/Linux terminal and such is limited to a tutorial of how to install cgminer and then common sense for other errors.